# Why Is My Callable Not Called From Inside a Lambda?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, callback

I have a function with the following signature:

```
void MyController::a(const Req &req, std::function<void (const Resp &)> &&callback, const std::string &slug);
```

Then there’s another function called from inside the first one with a very similar signature:

```
void MyController::page(const Req &req, const std::function<void (const Resp &)> &&callback, const std::string &slug);
```

I have the following call at the end of this function where the callback in `page()` is never called:

**Snippet 1**

```
addTicket(data, [=](auto id) {
    …
    page(req, std::move(callback), slug);
});
```

But this works:

**Snippet 2**

```
addTicket(data, [=](auto id) {
    …
});

page(req, std::move(callback), slug);
```

Why does snippet 2 work, but not snippet 1? Shouldn’t the callback variable be captured in the former case (`[=]`)?

Comment: what is page? please post a more complete example

Comment: I added the function signature of `page()` to the question.

Comment: Feels like the question wants to know the capture group behavior for ```lamdas``` defined inside function call as a parameter. I am curious as well.

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).